# How to update Map values of model MAP property on submit form in struts2?

Tags: struts2

### Struts2 textfield tag is not updating model property of map type

> price.xml

```
     <package name="priceList" namespace="/price" extends="struts-default">

    <default-interceptor-ref name="paramsPrepareParamsStack" />    

    <action name="PriceAction_*" method="{1}" class="billing.price.PriceAction">
        <result name="input">/price/PriceDetailList.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/price/PriceDetailList.jsp</result>
        <result name="list">/price/PriceList.jsp</result>
    </action>                       

 </package>
```

> PriceAction.java

```
public class PriceAction extends BaseAction
    implements ModelDriven, Preparable{

    private PriceList model;
    public PriceList getModel(){
        return model;
    }

    public void prepare() throws Exception{
        if(getRequestId() == 0){            
            model =  db.getBlankPriceList();
        }else{          
            model = (PriceList) db.get(getRequestId());
        }
    }

public class PriceList {
    private long id = System.nanoTime();
    private Date created = new Date();
    private Date effected;
    private String area;
    private String scheme;
    private Map prices = new HashMap();
    setters/getters...
}

public class Product {
    private long id = System.nanoTime();
    private String name;
    private String unit;    // Kg/Ltr
    private double wt;      // no.of pieces in decimal ex: 0.500 2.500 0.400
}

<s:iterator value="prices">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <s:textfield name="%{#key.priceListId}" readonly="true"  value="%{prices[key].priceListId}" size="15%"/>
        </td>                       
        <td>
            <s:textfield name="key.product.Id"  readonly="true" value="%{prices[key].product.Id}"  size="15%"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <s:textfield name="key.product.name"  readonly="true" value="%{prices[key].product.name}"  size="25%"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <s:textfield name="key.tax"  readonly="%{readOnly}" value="%{prices[key].tax}" size="5%"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <s:textfield name="key.superStockistPercent"  readonly="%{readOnly}" value="%{prices[key].superStockistPercent}" size="5%"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <s:textfield name="key.distributorPercent" readonly="%{readOnly}" value="%{prices[key].distributorPercent}"  size="5%"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <s:textfield name="key.agentPercent" readonly="%{readOnly}" value="%{prices[key].agentPercent}"  size="5%"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <s:textfield name="key.mrp" readonly="%{readOnly}" value="%{prices[key].mrp}" size="5%"/>
        </td>
    </tr>               
    </s:iterator>
</table>
```

> I am trying to update values of Model's map type of property but cant, please guide on this

All values update but map values are not.

[image]

> Map key is Long Map
>   I want to store prices in the map with product.id
>   following is PriceListService.jav in that i have created PriceList as model

```
public class PriceListService{
private static Map<Long, PriceList> priceLists = new HashMap<Long, PriceList> ();
static {
    Collection<Product> cols;
    HashMap<Long, Price> prices;
    Price price;
    double mrp;

    PriceList priceList1 = new PriceList( );
    try{
        priceList1.setEffected(new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyyMMdd" ).parse( "20170201" ));
    }catch(ParseException pe){pe.printStackTrace();}
    priceList1.setArea("Kolhapur, Ichalkaranji, Sangali, Karad, Satara");
    priceList1.setScheme("On Total 25Kg purchase 1Kg Srikhand or Amrakhand Free");

    prices = new HashMap<Long, Price>();
    cols =  new ProductService().getProducts();
    mrp = 0.00;
    for(Object o: cols){
        Product product = (Product) o;          
        price = new Price();
        mrp+=100.00;

        price.setPriceListId(priceList1.getId());
        price.setProduct(product);
        price.setMrp(mrp);
        price.setTax(6.50);
        price.setAgentPercent(18.00);
        price.setDistributorPercent(7.50);
        price.setSuperStockistPercent(3.50);

        prices.put(price.getProduct().getId(), price);          
    }
    priceList1.setPrices(prices);
    priceLists.put(priceList1.getId(), priceList1); 


    PriceList priceList2 = new PriceList( );
    try{
        priceList2.setEffected(new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyyMMdd" ).parse( "20170301" ));
    }catch(ParseException pe){pe.printStackTrace();}
    priceList2.setArea("Solapur, Pandharpur, Ajluj, Ratnagiri, Sindhudurg");
    priceList2.setScheme("On Total 30Kg purchase 1Kg Fruitkhand Free");

    prices = new HashMap<Long, Price>();
    cols = new ProductService().getProducts();
    mrp = 0.00;
    for(Object o: cols){
        Product product = (Product) o;          
        price = new Price();
        mrp+=1000.00;

        price.setPriceListId(priceList2.getId());
        price.setProduct(product);
        price.setMrp(mrp);
        price.setTax(6.50);
        price.setAgentPercent(20.00);
        price.setDistributorPercent(8.00);
        price.setSuperStockistPercent(3.00);

        prices.put(price.getProduct().getId(), price);          
    }
    priceList2.setPrices(prices);
    priceLists.put(priceList2.getId(), priceList2); 
}

public Collection getPriceLists(){

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.addAll ( priceLists.values() );
    return list;
}

public Object get(long id){
    return  priceLists.get(id);
}

public void save(Object object) {
    /* Persist product. */

    PriceList priceList = (PriceList) object;       
    priceLists.put( priceList.getId(), priceList);
    System.out.println(priceList.getArea() + " is saved successfuly.");
}

public void remove(Object object) {
    /* Remove Persisted product. */

    PriceList priceList = (PriceList) object;
    String area= ((PriceList) get(priceList.getId())).getArea();
    String effected = (((PriceList) get(priceList.getId())).getEffected()).toString();

    priceLists.remove(priceList.getId());
    System.out.println(area + " : " +  " is removed successfuly.");
}
```

}

Comment: Why did you use Map and what is a key type?